# Accessing common startup folder

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

The list of special folders in File System editor (**Add Special Folder** command) does not contain **Common Application Data** folder, but we can use **Custom Folder** command and set **DefaultLocation** Property to **[CommonAppDataFolder]** to get access to Common Application Data.

On the same line, there is no entry for **Common Startup Folder**. Is there a custom folder variable that I could use instead to get access to common startup folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be easier than I thought. Just select **User's Startup Folder** from the list of special folders and add your shortcuts in there. This special folder will point to All Users' Startup folder if user chooses to install the software for all users (by choosing **All Users** option during installation instead of **Just For Me**).

Answer (score 0):

There is no folder ID from what I know. Here is a [list with all the predefined folder IDs](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-paths.html) and some custom ones (the custom IDs are only available in Advanced Installer).

What you can try is to [use a custom action to defined the path of the folder](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-custom-folder.html) you need and set that in a custom folder, as we explain in the linked example.

I assume basic support for such operations is supported in VS.